# Can real number infinity be bigger than other real number infinity?

Tags: infinity, real-numbers

I know that 2 countable infinities are considered equal because you can pair each element in one set two an element in another one. But, for example, if we let all real numbers between 3 and 5 be equal to A, and all real numbers between 2 and 6 be equal to B, do we consider

B = A or B > A ?

I wasn't able to find the answer to this question anywhere, I'd really appreciate your help.

Comment: $B \cong A$. You can see this by writing down an explicit bijection $f : B \rightarrow A$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function $x\mapsto2x-4$ is a bijection between $[3,5]$ and $[2,6]$ hence these sets are *equipotent* (loosely speaking, they have the same size).

Comment: Thanks, that's actually pretty helpful example. I can't believe I was wrong...

Bests,
SmallCompetitor

Answer (score 1):

B = A, because there exists a bijection between [3,5] and [2,6], hence there are the same amount of real numbers is both intervals.